# Is there a way to enable ServiceFabric ApplicationGateway on Windows 7?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm using Windows 7 and I'm trying to run a local dev cluster with the ApplicationGateway (reverse proxy) functionality.

I looked at the following folder, that contains the cluster manifest templates:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure\FiveNode
```

And found that there's a different settings file for Windows 7, with the only difference being that "ApplicationGateway/Http" has "IsEnabled" set to false.

I tried the obvious thing of setting it to true, but couldn't get it to work, so I figured Windows 7 just doesn't support it.

I'm trying to understand if there's anything I can do to run it on Windows 7 anyway, or if the only way is to upgrade.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? It's been enabled by default for a few versions now I think

Comment: Runtime: 5.6.220.9494, SDK: 2.6.220.9494, Tools: 1.6.50508.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not supported on Windows 7.